# Is there a method to finding the proper coloring of graphs or is mostly guesswork?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm assuming there must be a way to narrow it down fast because how would you then do the problem with hundreds of vertices and edges? What is the method?

Comment: In general the problem is unfeasibly difficult. For special classes of graphs there are good algorithms, and for reasonable ones there are heuristics which help. There is a whole literature on the subject. You should Google a bit to see some of it.

Comment: The decision version of the graph coloring problem ("is there a proper coloring of a given graph with k colors?") is in general NP-complete. You can always get a coloring with at least as many colors as the chromatic number via say greedy coloring though (but it can be suboptimal, obviously).

Comment: The Wikipedia article on graph coloring has a section on algorithms. (Although I often find math.stackexchange explanations to be more enlightening than Wikipedia.)